# MongoDB - Saving DateTime as null?

Tags: mongodb

Can I save a DateTime as null in MongoDB?

Forgive my ignorance, I inherited this project and I'm not so familiar with Mongo. When looking at MongoVUE it says DateTime and is saved as an ISO string, but that [type is not included when I look at the Mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/).

Comment: That's just the way it's displayed, internally a binary date like C#'s `DateTime` is stored as a 64-bit integer [BSON Date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date).

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use MongoVUE. Use RoboMongo. It is much better, supported, available for all plaformes, and last but not least it is free.
2. I guess MongoVUE means `Date`.
3. Because mongoDB is schema-less you can save any type of data in any field.

Comment: You can't insert everything. Try to insert a non-BSON object. Good luck ;) Actually, you are limited to [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html)

Answer (score 0):

An ISO Date/Time string has the form

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm[:ss[.SSS]]TimeZoneOffset|"Z"
```

So for example the time of this writing (approximately) in my local time would be

```
2014-09-16T18:59+02:00
```

The letter T informs you that a date and a time is separated from each other. So when parsing an ISODate string, you can be absolutely positively sure that the part before the "T" is a date and the part after a T is a time.

The "Z" comes from the NATO alphabet naming for the letter Zulu, which historically denoted the NATO standard time which itself is equal to UTC since the 60s. So for short notation, UTC is referred to by this letter. The time of this writing would be written as

```
2014-09-16T16:59:00.000Z
```

in UTC.

Saving dates in MongoDB is easy, however. The MongoDB database drivers usually map the native date / datetime types of the programming language you use to the format used by MongoDB internally on save and vice versa when loading the data from the database.

So for example it is perfectly valid to do something like

```
var doc = { name:"FooBar", added: new Date()};
db.collection.save({doc});
```

in JavaScript or use Java's `java.util.Date`.

You discovered a little inconsistency in the docs, however. Whereas the type in the documentation you mentioned is referred to as Date, it is internally stored as an BSON Date. The BSON date itself is stored as a 64bit integer holding the milliseconds since [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) and is converted by the mongo shell and (iirc as an option by some of MongoDB drivers) to an ISO date formatted string.

And yes, you can save and deal with a null value for each given field.

Comment: It's not correct to say that MongoDB stores a date internally as an ISODate.  It's stored internally as a [BSON Date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date).  ISODate is just a Mongo shell JavaScript construct.

Comment: Right you are. Corrected that.